# Can't get ng-view with routing to work

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs, routes

I have looked through many questions with similar topics, but I can't find a solution that works for my code. I am trying to link my ng-view tag to an html fragment via its route, and I can't see what I am missing. I have simplified my problem and put it in [this plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/6N1ulUr1EniApJcLCIQm?p=preview) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to bootstrap angularjs. The simplest way to do this is to put the ng-app in the html tag:

```
<html ng-app="GATapp">
```

Also, your partial views (like the welcome-msg.html) does not need to have the html, head, and body tags. These tags already are present in the index.html.

Here is the up-to-date plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EDHyrw?p=preview